# How to pass shipping address value in paypal email?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

this is first time i'm develope paypal form , i have problem with shipping address how to get shipping address from customer and in email(see attach below) i want to insert into email from paypal ?

i don't know how to pass shipping address value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's in the docs with all the other values you can pass to paypal.

Comment: do you mean this <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">  or this <input type="hidden" name="address1" .. really confused..

Comment: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0J0VU

Comment: images with your question are not displaying, though answering below for your ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly 10 hidden variables which we've to pass to PayPal for Payment related process mentioned as below (this method is very Basic PayPal Payment option, apart from it PayPal provides few other payment options as well):

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="Merchant Account Email Address here">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http:// some url for notification purpose">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item name here">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="PayPal will return this value as it is in the same format, when it is in sending time, like some array values concat with some special character">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="Payment Amount here as decimal for ex. 50.00">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http:// return url here, after payment to our website">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="paynow">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
```

You can just send above hidden variables to PayPal and set required `URL` as per your demo server website path.

Keep in mind to keep `developer.paypal.com` account `logged in` while you're checking with `PayPal Sandbox (test mode) account`. It will be required.

Thanks !

Comment: thanks..but what is field for shipping address (i mean i want show address too in email when someone buy) this "address1" ?

Comment: There comes a `custom` named variable just like above hiddens where you can pass any custom information and PayPal will return that values as it is passed. However I don't think you will need to pass shipping address to PayPal, you can get it from session or via storing that information in database with cart_id or something.. PayPal just needs above information only to process with Payment

Comment: actually..my point is in admin email there have address from customer...if you see above image i only dont have address from customer...

Comment: hmm, i really cannot see above images in your question, please post them again if possible